# Why do DataFlavors change after restarting the program?

Tags: java, clipboard

I wrote this method

```
public static void printFlavors() {
    Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable transferData = systemClipboard.getContents(null);
    for (DataFlavor dataFlavor : transferData.getTransferDataFlavors()) {
        System.out.println(dataFlavor);
    }
}
```

Using Java I write a string to my clipboard then I call `printFlavors()` and get

```
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-serialized-object;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=unicode]
```

When I first stop the program and then run a new program calling `printFlavors()` I get a totally different result:

```
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-serialized-object;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=unicode]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
```

Why does the result change?

Comment: It may possibly also be related to an odd behavior I just observed and [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059538/java-clipboard-error-bug/41462225#41462225) about: Getting clipboard text always reflects text copied by the user, but if the program itself sets the text, that's all content I get afterwards **except** if I postpone further clipboard text getting via SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). Dragan Bozanovic's answer might effectively be related to that, because the underlying pausing-effect might be the very same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you added content to clipboard using something like:

```
systemClipboard.setContents(new StringSelection("abc"), null);
```

Then, when you read available data flavors, I assume that Clipboard is able to exactly determine what the type of clipboard content is (it is StringSelection to which it still has a reference) and it knows exactly what type of content it is (encoding, etc).

If you pause the execution of the program (by thread-sleeping or debug break point) after you programmatically set the clipboard content, and then change the clipboard content outside of the program (by copying some text for example), you should get the same output as if you restarted the app (many more data flavors to help to convert the content to a Java representation), because the content came from the outer world (Operating System).

I worked a little bit with java Clipboard in the past and these are my assumptions; as always it is best to check the source code if you really need to know what's going on exactly.

**EDIT**

I took a look at the source code, and my assumption is correct - when the app stores StringSelection to clipboard, it keeps reference to it until the clipboard content changes and returns only data flavors supported by StringSelection:

```
private static final DataFlavor[] flavors = {
   DataFlavor.stringFlavor,
   DataFlavor.plainTextFlavor // deprecated
};
```